# Documentation of HTML canvas 2D transformations using SVGMatrix

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, matrix, 2d

I'm looking at using an HTML canvas element for a simple game, but have had trouble finding complete documentation of certain features regarding the 2D drawing context. Usually I would look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), but there are still things missing from there.

In particular, even when I looked at the [HTML Canvas 2D Context W3C Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#transformations) (which I understand to be the official word on the subject), I can't seem to find out more about using the `SVGMatrix` object for transformations.

Both links I've given describe transformation functions on the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` object that take the individual elements of a matrix as arguments. For example:

`context.transform(a, b, c, d, e, f)`

However, the links also have these notes:

> The methods listed below remain for historical and compatibility
>   reasons as SVGMatrix objects are used in most parts of the API
>   nowadays and will be used in the future instead.

> Most of the API uses SVGMatrix objects rather than this API. This API
>   remains mostly for historical reasons

Despite the pages saying that most of the API now uses `SVGMatrix` objects instead of specifying individual matrix elements, I can't seem to find documentation for this.

Can someone point me to some official documentation, or otherwise describe the API that makes use of `SVGMatrix` objects instead of specifying individual matrix elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer may have more the form of a blurb than actual solid information, but given the circumstances I hope it still can give some input.

There is not much documentation of its usage - there are still (I believe) discussion about exposing as well as how to implement it (with canvas/paths) which is why we don´t see much of it yet. Canvas has (or had?) a method `currentTransform` which would return a `SVGMatrix` object, but it is not widely supported, or is hidden behind experimental flags (ie. in Chrome. disclaimer: may have changed recently).

You can read one thread of the [discussion here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2014Mar/0169.html).

Its use is also mentioned [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Transformations) but not documented further.

I would assume in the case of canvas, that in the future you could pass in a retrieved and modified object to f.ex. `setTransform()` as an "overloaded" option to the existing signature (much like the `Path2D` object can be to stroke and fill), although there is no hint of this in the recommendation (see how it's used with SVG below for a likely usage pattern).

The object does the same as `setTransform()/transform()` though, you would initialize it with values for a-e through the use the same methods (as the properties themselves are read-only) as with the context, so there is no difference in principle (looking at the source code for the open source browser will show exactly how it's being used).

See also [this article](http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/matrix-transforms-in-svg/) (more for SVG and how to use the object).

To play around with the current implementation of the object itself in f.ex. console, you can do:

```
var matrix = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg')
             .createSVGMatrix();
```

PS: Also feel free to check out my own [matrix implementation (MIT)](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially the discussion link. So my understanding now is that although the documentation says the given API is only there for historical reasons, it's not actually a historical API yet. It's actually the current, and only, canvas transformation API – and all that is meant by those notes is that it's expected to soon be deprecated. Basically I originally misunderstood what those notes were saying.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's much more to say on this question for now, so I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one, and maybe when the matrix-based API is finalised someone else will answer with a reference to official documentation on it.